# CodeIgniter multipIe image thumbnailing issue:

Tags: codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter Image thumbnailing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894350/codeigniter-image-thumbnailing-issue)

I want to create two thumbnails withh different sizes for same image. In my code only first thumbnail code created
and following error occured.
Error: "Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image."

```
function createThumb1($imageName)  //file name passed
{   


        // this thumbnail created
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    echo $config['source_image']    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'.$imageName;

    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
    $config['width']     = 80;
    $config['height']   = 80;
    $config['new_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/uploads/thumbs/'.$imageName;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();}

    $this->image_lib->clear();

    // unable to create this this thumbnail
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    echo $config['source_image']    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/'.$imageName;
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
    $config['width']     = 696;
    $config['height']   = 241;
    $config['new_image'] =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/uploads/'.$imageName;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();}


    $this->image_lib->clear();






    $this->load->view('admin/upload_form',array('error' => ' ' ));





}
```

please solve my problem I am working on its since last week and problem get not resolved

Comment: I am using jpg,jpeg,png files, if I add GD library even then issue not resolved please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the GD lib at all, but I have two thoughts. In the 2nd part you have `$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;` What happens if you set that to `TRUE`? And what happens if you just comment out the first part and only run the 2nd?

Answer (score 0):

Your using GD library for resizing the image which is not installed/not properly configured on the machine. Installing GD may fix the issue.

[GD php.net Page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Comment: If problem is with GD library then why one thumbnail created? No issue eith GD library

Comment: No Need of any other library required :-(
problem can be resolved if we load image library only once, in start of the function.
and only initialized config for second thumb. successful code is as under for conveyance:-{}