# CodeIgniter Upload Image Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a thumbnail and save it on my target location. however when I tried to save it it gives me an error.

`message error: <p>Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file directory are writable.</p>`

here's my code:

**controller**

```
public function insert_new_employee(){
    //users table
    $user_role_id = $this->input->post('user_role');
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');


    //personal info
    $file_path = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i a'));
    $type = explode("/", $_FILES["image_path"]['type']);

    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
    $employee_code = $this->input->post('employee_code');
    $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
    $position = $this->input->post('position');
    $birthdate = $this->input->post('birthdate');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $avatar = $_FILES['image_path']['tmp_name'];

    $this->user_role_m->do_resize($avatar);
}
```

**model**

```
public function do_resize($filename)
{
    $source_path = $filename;
    $target_path = base_url()."includes/avatars/thumbnail/";
    $config_manip = array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => $source_path,
        'new_image' => $target_path,
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'create_thumb' => TRUE,
        'thumb_marker' => '_thumb',
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 150
    );
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
    // clear //
    $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

it's my first time encountering this error.. so please bear with me...I also tried to check the permission of the target folder and chmod is on full control...

Comment: As the error says, make this folder base_url()."includes/avatars/thumbnail/" writtable.

Comment: @ToshoTrajanov as I've said on my post I already did... but don't know what's causing this error.

Comment: echo `$target_path` value and check what it return

Comment: hello @Saty, here's the link of the target url `http://192.168.1.31:8080/spms/includes/avatars/thumbnail/`

Comment: Try to use absolute file path instead of base_url().

Comment: That' s wrong use it as  `$target_path = getcwd() ."/includes/avatars/thumbnail/";`

Comment: @ToshoTrajanov I also did... I've tried several solutions and google but to no avail it  still gives me error.

Comment: Change your target path to  `FCPATH . "includes/avatars/thumbnail/";` also you must set your base url in config.php if your using codeigniter 3 versions

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I set the config of my base_url in config.php...

Comment: it now generate a file however it has a .tmp file extension...

Comment: @SamTengWong Have you tried change tmp to just name `$avatar = $_FILES['image_path']['name'];`

Comment: seems someone already found a solution! check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894350/codeigniter-image-thumbnailing-issue

Comment: hello guys..., I happen to solve the problem... by using the root directory.. `./includes/avatars/thumbnail`